# Why is the change in an html input textbox not being detected in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a repeater, one column of which contains a textbox on which is attached a JQuery datepicker along with an update button. So a user uses the datepicker to change the date, clicks update and it writes to the database.The original date and the record id are stored in hidden fields.

```html
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
<ItemTemplate>
<tr>

<td>
<asp:HiddenField ID="hidThisID" Value='<%# Eval("orderID") %>' runat="server" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="hidPrevDueDate" Value='<%# Eval("Duebeforedate", "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}") %>' runat="server" />
<input type="text" class="form-control fc-datepicker duedateinput" style="width: 150px" value='<%# Eval("Duebeforedate", "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}") %>'  runat="server" id="fccd" readonly />
<asp:LinkButton ID="btnDateUpdate" OnClick="btnDateUpdate_Click" CssClass="btn btn-primary btn-sm" runat="server" ToolTip="Approved"> Update </asp:LinkButton>
</td>

</tr>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

which calls this function

```html
protected void btnDateUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (RepeaterItem item in Repeater1.Items)
        {
            HtmlInputText htmlDueDate = (HtmlInputText)item.FindControl("fccd");
            HiddenField hidID = (HiddenField)item.FindControl("hidThisID");
            HiddenField hidOldDate = (HiddenField)item.FindControl("hidPrevDueDate");
            DateTime prevDueDate = Convert.ToDateTime(hidOldDate.Value.ToString());
            DateTime newDueDate = Convert.ToDateTime(htmlDueDate.Value.ToString());
            string ID = hidID.Value;
            if (prevDueDate != newDueDate)
            {
                string query = "update [tblOrders] set Duebeforedate=CONVERT(datetime,'" + newDueDate.ToString() + "', 103) where  [orderID] =  '" + ID + "'";
                
                //database stuff here
            }
        }
    }
```

However, the newDueDate variable still holds the original due date. Consequently the old and new dates match and so the database doesn't get updated. How do I get it to store the new value?

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. You should not concatenate any string value coming from the client side directly to your SQL query. Use parameterized (prepared) queries, or do some escaping on the values coming from the client-side

Answer (score 0):

For two-way data binding you need to use the *Bind* keyword instead of *Eval*

Comment: I did change Eval to Bind but it has made no difference.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it, it wasn't the btnUpdate function at all, I'd forgotten this check -

```html
if (!IsPostBack)
{
     //bind the repeater
}
```